# Swing Button has weird border

Tags: java, swing

I have a blackjack game, and the GUI is created using swing. One of my buttons looks completely normal, and the other one has a weird border around the text. Both buttons were made using Intellij IDEA's built-in GUI form, and I copied the normal looking one to make the weird looking one.

Here's what the button looks like (compared to the normal one).

[Can't embed images lol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdJ2w.png)

Comment: Try hitting the tab key to move between the buttons. Does the 'weird border' change between buttons? If so it's to display input focus. If not, post a [mre] and a better description of what 'weird' means to you.

Comment: Maybe method [setFocusPainted](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setFocusPainted(boolean)), in class `javx.swing.AbstractButton` (which is parent class of `JButton`), is appropriate?